# Elastic Search- Fetch Distinct Tags

Tags: elasticsearch

I have document of following format:

```
{
 _id :"1",
  tags:["guava","apple","mango", "banana", "gulmohar"]
}


{
  _id:"2",
  tags: ["orange","guava", "mango shakes", "apple pie", "grammar"]
}

{

  _id:"3",
  tags: ["apple","grapes", "water", "gulmohar","water-melon", "green"]
}
```

Now, I want to fetch unique tags value from whole document 'tags field' starting with prefix `g*`, so that these unique tags will be display by tag suggestors(Stackoverflow site is an example).

For example: Whenever user types, '`g`':
`"guava", "gulmohar", "grammar", "grapes" and  "green"` should be returned as a result.
ie. the query should returns distinct tags with prefix g*.

I tried everywhere, browse whole documentations, searched es forum, but I didn't find any clue, much to my dismay.

I tried aggregations, but aggregations returns the distinct count for whole words/token in tags field. It does not return the unique list of tags starting with 'g'.

```
"query": {
    "filtered": {
      "query": {
        "bool": {
          "should": [
            {
              "query_string": {
                "allow_leading_wildcard": false,
                "fields": [
                  "tags"
                ],
                "query": "g*",
                "fuzziness":0
              }
            }
          ]
        }
      },
      "filter": {
         //some condition on other  field...
      }

    }

  },
  "aggs": {
    "distinct_tags": {
      "terms": {
        "field": "tags",
        "size": 10
      }
    }
  },
```

result of above: guava(w), apple(q), mango(1),...

Can someone please suggest me the correct way to fetch all the distinct tags with prefix input_prefix*?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It's a bit of a hack, but this seems to accomplish what you want.

I created an index and added your docs:

```
DELETE /test_index

PUT /test_index
{
   "settings": {
      "number_of_shards": 1,
      "number_of_replicas": 0
   }
}

POST /test_index/_bulk
{"index":{"_index":"test_index","_type":"doc","_id":1}}
{"tags":["guava","apple","mango", "banana", "gulmohar"]}
{"index":{"_index":"test_index","_type":"doc","_id":2}}
{"tags": ["orange","guava", "mango shakes", "apple pie", "grammar"]}
{"index":{"_index":"test_index","_type":"doc","_id":3}}
{"tags": ["guava","apple","grapes", "water", "grammar","gulmohar","water-melon", "green"]}
```

Then I used a combination of [prefix query](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/guide/current/prefix-query.html) and [highlighting](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-request-highlighting.html) as follows:

```
POST /test_index/_search
{
   "query": {
      "prefix": {
         "tags": {
            "value": "g"
         }
      }
   },
   "fields": [ ], 
   "highlight": {
       "pre_tags": [""],
       "post_tags": [""], 
       "fields": {
           "tags": {}
       }
   }
}
...
{
   "took": 5,
   "timed_out": false,
   "_shards": {
      "total": 1,
      "successful": 1,
      "failed": 0
   },
   "hits": {
      "total": 3,
      "max_score": 1,
      "hits": [
         {
            "_index": "test_index",
            "_type": "doc",
            "_id": "1",
            "_score": 1,
            "highlight": {
               "tags": [
                  "guava",
                  "gulmohar"
               ]
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "test_index",
            "_type": "doc",
            "_id": "2",
            "_score": 1,
            "highlight": {
               "tags": [
                  "guava",
                  "grammar"
               ]
            }
         },
         {
            "_index": "test_index",
            "_type": "doc",
            "_id": "3",
            "_score": 1,
            "highlight": {
               "tags": [
                  "guava",
                  "grapes",
                  "grammar",
                  "gulmohar",
                  "green"
               ]
            }
         }
      ]
   }
}
```

Here is the code I used:
http://sense.qbox.io/gist/c14675ee8bd3934389a6cb0c85ff57621a17bf11

What you're trying to do amounts to autocomplete, of course, and there are perhaps better ways of going about that than what I posted above (though they are a bit more involved). Here are a couple of blog posts we did about ways to set up autocomplete:

http://blog.qbox.io/quick-and-dirty-autocomplete-with-elasticsearch-completion-suggest

http://blog.qbox.io/multi-field-partial-word-autocomplete-in-elasticsearch-using-ngrams

Comment: Thank you. But this is not the expected result. This does not give the list of unique tags across whole document tag fields.
 
Here, I will need to scan all the hits one by one, and have to put  each of the tag entry in a hashmap like datastructure, is n't it?
`"tags": [
                  "guava",
                  "gulmohar"
               ]`,`  "tags": [
                  "guava",
                  "grammar"
               ]`,` "tags": [
                  "guava",
                  "grapes",
                  "grammar",
                  "gulmohar",
                  "green"
              ]`

Comment: With your implementation, i need to scan each entry in each hit and keep each of them in a hash map.
I think, the third document created a little confusion, so edited the example in question, to make it more clear.

Comment: Honestly I don't think there is a way to do precisely what you are asking. You will probably have to write a tiny bit of processing code to get the result structure you are looking for. Elasticsearch will do the heavy lifting, but you might have to write a for loop to process the results.

Alternatively, you could change the structure of your data so that each document only has one tag. Then filtering the documents down to those that match the prefix is pretty easy. You'll still have to write a for loop to process the hits though.

Comment: And, of course, the two links I posted explain a couple of different ways to set up autocomplete. Both will require changing the structure of your data, though. Everything is a trade-off.

Comment: I was able to achieve the goal by following your suggestions and two blog post links mentioned in your answer. Accepting the answer as your suggestion worked like charm, and you showed me the right direction.

Answer (score 1):

As per @Sloan Ahrens advice, I did following:

Updated the mapping:

```
  "tags": {
      "type": "completion",
      "context": {
        "filter_color": {
          "type": "category",
          "default": "",
          "path": "fruits.color"
        },
        "filter_type": {
          "type": "category",
          "default": "",
          "path": "fruits.type"
        }
      }
   }
```

Reference: [ES API Guide](http://www.elasticsearch.org/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/suggester-context.html)

Inserted these indexes:

```
{
 _id :"1",
  tags:{input" :["guava","apple","mango", "banana", "gulmohar"]},
  fruits:{color:'bar',type:'alice'}
}


{
  _id:"2",
   tags:{["orange","guava", "mango shakes", "apple pie", "grammar"]}
   fruits:{color:'foo',type:'bob'}
}

{

  _id:"3",
  tags:{ ["apple","grapes", "water", "gulmohar","water-melon", "green"]}
  fruits:{color:'foo',type:'alice'}
}
```

I don't need to modify much, my original index. Just added `input` before tags array.

```
POST rescu1/_suggest?pretty'
{
  "suggest": {
    "text": "g",
    "completion": {
      "field": "tags",
      "size": 10,
      "context": {
        "filter_color": "bar",
        "filter_type": "alice"
      }
    }
  }
}
```

gave me the desired output.

*I accepted @Sloan Ahrens answer as his suggestions worked like a charm for me, and he showed me the right direction.*